# How do I keep sibling divs from pushing each other down when I use "margin-top: 4px" on one of them?

Tags: html, css

I have a very simple navigation bar with five buttons. Each of them starts with `box-shadow: 0px 4px #777777` to give a 3D look, and there is a `.navbarright a { display: inline-block }` as well to line up all the buttons horizontally. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="navbarright">
    <a href="x"><div class="navbutton" id="x"> x </div></a>
    <a href="x"><div class="navbutton" id="x"> x </div></a>
    <a href="x"><div class="navbutton" id="x"> x </div></a>
    <a href="x"><div class="navbutton" id="x"> x </div></a>
    <a href="x"><div class="navbutton" id="x"> x </div></a>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS I am using to attempt to create a button-pressing effect upon hover:

```
.navbutton:hover {
    margin-top: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px #777777;
}
```

Basically, upon hover, it gets rid of the shadow (which represents the front-facing side of the 3D button) and moves the button down to replace the area where the shadow was, to give the appearance that the button was pressed all the way down. I may change it later so that it only presses down half-way, which is why the `#777777` is still part of the `box-shadow` in `.navbutton:hover`.

The mechanism works, but the CSS seems to apply "margin-top: 4px" to all of the other navigation buttons too. It does not remove the shadows on them as well, however.

How can I fix it so that only one of the buttons adjusts its top margin upon hover and not all five of them?

Comment: Why not just use plain CSS? `.navbutton:hover {...}` ?

Comment: Hah, good point. Removed the jQuery and added in plain CSS, but it still seems to have the same problem.

Comment: Post it to a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the CSS

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to your navbarright a, where you also have display: inline-block.

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZmS9/).

display: inline-block keeps everything in a tight block, when one div moves down so do the rest. vertical-align: top makes the divs aligned with the tallest element, keeping them in place while you move individual ones down.

Comment: My in-depth understanding of CSS isn't as good as others, but I did my best adding in an explanation. If anyone else would care to chime in with a better, more accurate explanation, please feel free.

Comment: Thanks, saw your edit and I understand now. Really appreciate it.